# How to display two different type of images in SSRS report for a Boolean field

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am working on a SSRS report. I have a field called IsAllergic in database which could be 1, 0 or NULL. The business requirement is Yes and No side by side in report. If Yes then show a checked image infront of Yes and unchecked infront of No. 
I have tried the following. 
For the Yes checkbox under Use this image I use the below query:

```
=switch(Fields!IsAllergic .Value <> 1, "unchecked", Fields!IsAllergic .Value = 1, "checked")
```

I have set the Visibility when the report initially run to "Show".

For the No checkbox under Use this image I use the below query:

```
=switch(Fields!IsAllergic Value <> 1, "checked", Fields!IsAllergic .Value = 1, "unchecked")
```

For this checkbox also I have set the Visibility when the report initially run to "Show".

When I run the report I get the opposite result. Yes shows an unchecked checkbox image and No shows checked checkbox. 
What am I missing here?
Been looking at this for hours and help is appreciated!

Comment: There are syntax errors in the example. Also if you are not testing for nulls you might as well use IIF instead of switch.

Answer (score 1):

I've just put together a quick sample to test and essentially what you are doing should be OK (except for the typos). However you can simplify it.

Step-by-step
I created a new report and added a new dataset. The dataset query is as follows (just to produce some sample data)

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Name varchar(50), IsAllergic int) 

INSERT INTO @t
VALUES        
('Bob', 1), 
('Dave', 0), 
('Mike', NULL), 
('Tony', 1), 
('Rick', 0), 
('Steve', NULL)
                                                                                                               SELECT * FROM @t
```

Next I added two images, one was a box with a green check and one with the red cross but obviously swap these out for you checked and unchecked images.

Next I added a simple table with three columns, name in the first column and then images in the 2nd and 3rd columns.

The expressions for the image value properties is this...
For the YES column

```
=SWITCH(
Fields!IsAllergic.Value = 1, "checkboxchecked",
True, "checkboxcrossed"
)
```

For the NO column

```
=SWITCH(
Fields!IsAllergic.Value = 1, "checkboxcrossed",
True, "checkboxchecked"
)
```

By using `SWITCH` like this we are only really testing the first condition, the `TRUE` condition acts like an `ELSE` catching anything that fails the first condition, including NULLs.

The report design look something like this

[image]

That's it, no other properties were changed.
The output looks like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using IIf instead of switch. 
Below is what I did.

```
=IIf(Fields!IsAllergic.Value <> True, "checked", "unchecked")
```

This handles NULLs too. If IsAllergic is NULL or 0 then it shows unchecked checkbox and for true it shows checked chkbox.